# Django complex partitioning & ordering for tree Table

Tags: python, sql, django, database, postgresql

I'm using Django with PostgreSQL as my Backend-Stack for an application of which the main feature is a complex, multilevel table displaying annotated time-series-data for different products.

So basically I've got 2 models defined, one is **Product** and the other one **Timestamp**, while the Product Model is hierarchial and uses the **MPTT** library for implementing the tree-structure.
Each product can have multiple children, with **4 levels of depth** as maximum and has multiple Timestamps, describing data for how they performed on a certain date. Thus I'm basically annotating all time-series data for each product in a queryset and that works flawlessly. **The Problem** which I'm facing is that I need to **order** the products dynamically by their **annotated values**, without destroying their position in the **hierarchy** and/or **parent-child relationships**. When I use some basic **order_by("tree_id", "level" ...)** like method, the **parent-child relationships get 'overwritten'**. Also **Important** is that every Product-root **has it's own tree_id and is a separate tree**.

models.py

```
class Product(MPTTModel):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    budget = models.FloatField(null=True)
    creation_date = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True)
    parent = parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null=True, blank=True)

class Timestamp(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    viewed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bought = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    shown = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

A very basic mockup of how the table should look can be seen below.[image]

My current function for the queryset ordering does not work correctly and can be seen here

```
  filters = self.request.GET
  d_start, d_end = filters["date_start"], filters["date_end"]
  

  qs=Product._tree_manager.get_queryset_descendants(Product.objects.filter(
     Exists(Timestamp.objects.filter(
         date__gte=d_start,
         date__lte=d_end,
         product=OuterRef("pk"))
         ), level=0), include_self=True).annotate(
            viewed=(Sum("timestamp__viewed")),
            bought=(Sum("timestamp__bought")),
            shown=(Sum("timestamp__shown"))).order_by("tree_id", "level", "bought")
```

The Result of this looks like this:
[image]

I suspect that the solution will require some **Raw SQL**, maybe **Partitioning** combined with ordering.

I'm looking forward for your answers and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

postgreSQL'S Recursive CTEs turned out to be what I needed.

Django's ORM is very reliable and robust, but it has it's limits.
Complex, architecture dependant features like Recursive Queries can't be implemented using the ORM - at least not at the time I'm writing this answer.

Thus this was a scenario which required me to write raw SQL instead.
I can't include the SQL code here as it contains sensible backend information & logic.

But I can tell you a few things if you should ever have to deal with hierarchial models / queries in Django.

- DO NOT use libraries like **Mptt** or **TreeBeard** if performance is a major priority. They are both pretty slow and in my scenario not qualified for production usage as UX would suffer tremendously due to longer loading times.
- DO NOT hesitate to use **Raw-SQL Queries** just because Django provides an ORM.
  Sooner or later you'll run into a problem which the ORM is not able to solve because of it's **high abstraction level**.
- DO NOT waste your precious time trying to **reinvent the wheel**.
- If you **have** to work with a **Relational Database** to solve this issue for whatever reason, then use **PostgreSQL** as it offers the best performance, features and extensions for solving this issue (I personally think PostgreSQL is by far the best SQL-DB out there atm.)
- Use the **ltree** extension for your queries. It's very intuitive and easy to understand, you can read it up in the thorough **postgres-docs**.
- If you have to **order siblings** without destroying the hierarchial structure, use an **Array** combined with **ROW OVER**.

Overall-Performance was around 10x faster in my scenario when I migrated from **Mptt** to **CTEs**.

Useful links:

- CTEs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html
- Ltree extension https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ltree.html

Comment: Can you share the code for your solution? That will help future readers without similar questions.

Comment: @JeremyCaney    Well, the code ended up to be a 200 lines long raw-sql query, containing rather sensitive data concerning the database. But I can describe in detail how I solved the problem and what NOT to do when being confronted with it.